# In react what does (obj: any) => boolean do?

Tags: reactjs

So I have this code:

```
const checkResponse = (
  response: AxiosResponse,
  typeCheck: (obj: any) => boolean
): Error | undefined => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    // console.log(typeof(response.data));
    if (typeCheck(response.data)) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return Error(`Invalid json response: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
    }
  } else {
    return new Error(`${response.status} from server`);
  }
};
```

Some qns: are `response` and `typeCheck` parameters to the function `checkResponse`?
And is `typeCheck` also a function?
And what does `typeCheck(response.data)` do? Obviously `response.data` is passed to  `typeCheck` but then what?
To me (not a react or fucntional programmer) it doesn't look like `typeCheck` does anything.

Comment: It does. `typeCheck: (obj: any) => boolean` means `typeCheck` is an arrow function that takes an argument `obj` of type `any` and always returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some qns: are response and typeCheck parameters to the function checkResponse?

> And is typeCheck also a function?

Yes to both.

> what does `(obj: any) => boolean` do?

This is TypeScript syntax. It indicates a type of a function which takes a single argument, named `obj`, which can be anything, and returns a boolean. Here, it's being used to verify that the response is of the expected format. For example, one might be expecting the response to be of the structure

```
{
  userid: number
}
```

in which case, you could pass the following `typeCheck` function to `checkResponse`:

```
checkResponse(
  response,
  (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false;
    if (typeof (obj as { userid: unknown }).userid !== number) return false;
  }
);
```

This implements the JavaScript logic needed to check that the payload is an object with a `userid` property, whose value is a number.

> Obviously response.data is passed to typeCheck but then what?

It'll verify that the response is of the expected type. If not, it'll throw an error - otherwise, it'll do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. But those are the only occurrences of `typeCheck ` defined anywhere in the code. So if it is not defined anywhere else what would it do?

Comment: The parameter is defined in the function and called, so if the function is ever called, that's what it'll do. There may well not be further references to `typeCheck`, but if the function is used at all, the second parameter passed to the function will be something of the type `typeCheck`, even if it's not named such.

Comment: Ah yes, just figured that out, after I posted my comment! Many thanks.